# Integration of Looker Action Hub (GCS) in LookML

Tags: google-cloud-storage, looker, lookml

I have successfully connected to GCS in Looker Action Hub using SA key and when I manually try to send the report to GCS through UI is working where I have to specify the bucket.

What I am trying to achieve and stuck is to create a button on the report allowing the user to export the data to GCS instead of doing it through Send/schedule option using the already working GCS Action Hub using LookML in view.

I have gone through official documentation where it mentions using tags in measure but is very unclear to understand.

Thanks,
Abhijeet Kotkar